# How can I stop the Apache server creating error_log files?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, error-log

Is there a way to stop Apache creating error_log files using .htaccess ?

Comment: No, there is no way to do this.

Comment: NO, this should be on serverfault.com anyhow.

Comment: As others have said, it doesn't make sense to disable Apache's error_log using .htaccess.  But if you clarify what problem you're trying to solve by disabling the error_log, maybe we can figure out alternative approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably no way to do that apart doing something funny like

```
ErrorLog "|/bin/true"
```

has you can see in the [manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#errorlog) this directive is only available in a server config and a virtualhost. If you want to delete certain log entry for particular URLS, you can make a script that would filter those lines and use something like:

```
ErrorLog "|/path/to/your/script.pl"
```

On the same fashion you can lower the log level to pretty much nothing with [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#loglevel):

```
LogLevel emerg
```

this won't avoid having the file but it would be probably few lines long or 0 byte. Also you cannot use `.htaccess` to that, you have to have access to the server config.

Last point, I am not really sure what you are intending to do but log files are valuable security information and you might need them in case you have to investigate some problems,  security events (hack, audit) or even statistics. If it's a problem you have too much logs, I advice you to take a look at log rotation software, maybe [cronolog](http://cronolog.org/usage.html) would help you to manage it better.